# Detect a Variable Exists in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello I am rather new to jQuery and have a situation here.

I am actually setting default position on document.ready as below

```
$('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
```

now this works perfectly when this is placed on the page containing .categorytitle class

The issue arises when the script cannot find .categorytitle class in the document

I tried the below code but it did not work

```
if($('.categorytitle').length!= 0){
     $('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
}
```

Can anyone help on a way I can find if .categorytitle exists in the page?

Many thanks!

This is the complete code I am trying to implement.

```
        if($('.categorytitle').length){
        $('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
        if($('.categorytext').length){
        $('.categorytext').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
        if($('.models').length){
        $('.models').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
```

I get "f is undefined" is the jQuery ScrollTo Script file. Seems like the $(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href') is undefined and so this error.

Comment: what was the problem with that code? would it not run when you had a .categorytitle class?

Comment: Seems like if($('.categorytitle').length) should work, lemme try and get back. cheers!

Comment: @mazlix - it runs when I have .categorytitle class but throws an error when I don't - so I was looking for a way to check if the element exists.

Comment: does http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/vAjDB/2/ throw any errors for you?

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Pushpinder, are you sure your problem comes from `.categorytitle` instead of `$(".people .sants a.modeling")` not matching anything, and therefore `attr('href')` returning `undefined`?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Thanks for the response, I too think this may be the cause ... researching on it...

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('.categorytitle')){
     $('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
}
```

try this one

Comment: thanks for the reply - I posted the code in the question albeit also solved the error with the help of all you folks here. Posted the answer also below. Cheers!

Comment: I still see no html in your question

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me... what's the problem http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/vAjDB/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/vAjDB/

this code works for me:

```
<div class="notcategorytitle">
    blahbalbhalh
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if($('.categorytitle').length!= 0){
     alert('hit');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure why it isn't working, still I am trying to debug if there is some other error causing this to appear. thanks for the rely!

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to just do

`if ($('.categorytitle').length){
       //your code here
}`

Comment: in situations like this when your code seems like it should work, your area probably resides somewhere silly that you wouldn't expect. I kind of suspect your error may be in the $('.people .sants a.modeling') selector you have there

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Evan - I too think as Frederick above highlighted that may be the $(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href') is not being found and is returning "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

One way to ignore all possible errors in that line is to just catch and ignore exceptions in it:

```
try {
    $('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
} catch(e) {}
```

Comment: I get "f is undefined" is the jQuery ScrollTo Script file. Seems like the $(".people .sants a.modeling").attr('href') is undefined and so this error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Big thanks to all of you here - just a matter of seconds and you folks saved me hours of debugging - super cheers to you folks.

Below is the solution

```
        if($('.categorytitle').length && $(".people a.modeling").length){
            $('.categorytitle').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
        if($('.categorytext').length && $(".people a.modeling").length){
            $('.categorytext').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
        if($('.models').length && $(".people a.modeling").length){
            $('.models').scrollTo($(".people a.modeling").attr('href'), 750, {easing:'easeOutExpo'});
        }
    }
```

not only was the .categorytitle not being found as suggested by you folks, .people.a.modeling was also not found, so I checked for both.

Cheers to all of you here!